# PHP gives error when tryng to require a file that does exist

Tags: php

The directory i am trying to require is `C:\xampp\htdocs\ulogin\ulogin\config\all.inc.php`

I am using this code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
echo $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] .'/ulogin/ulogin/config/all.inc.php';
require_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] .'/ulogin/ulogin/config/all.inc.php');
```

Yet I get this error:

```
C:/xampp/htdocs/ulogin/ulogin/config/all.inc.php
Warning: require_once(./ulogin/ulogin/main.inc.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\ulogin\installCheck.php on line 6
```

It shows the correct directory but yet fails to require it

Comment: use `realpath($path)`. It will turn relative paths into absolute paths. If it returns false, the path is wrong.

Comment: If you hardcode the path does it work?

Comment: @RobFos what is hardcode

Comment: something is wrong here. `echo $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` outputs the path, but in the `require_once` warning, it does not exists. Here we have 4 lines of code, but the error is on `line 6`, so what else do you have there?

Comment: @mitkosoft Good spot. in the question OP says they are trying to include `all.inc.php` but the error actaully says `main.inc.php`

Comment: @Neverdie Welcome to SO, Hardcode means you are giving the value as a raw text. eg. if you give directly `C:/xampp/htdocs` in your php file is hardcode instead you need to give `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]`

Comment: I try to require  more paths on the next lines but they al give me the same error

Comment: could you please share the line where you are including `main.inc.php`!

Comment: @Neverdie As @mitkosoft has picked up on. It doesn't look like your issue is with the inclusion of the `all.inc.php` file. it seems to be with the `main.inc.php` file. Please check your path for this file and if possible, post the relevant code.

Comment: There are two `/ulogin` in your path... is it correct?